# php - Работа с датами

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

вопрос вот такого плана.
Форма регистрации/авторизации.

Нужно в классе в деструкторе проверять пользователей у кого истекло время регистрации и удалять.

Сообственно сам вопрос как проверять пользователя. У меня к примеру в базу вставляется дата типа date(mktime()). Я так понимаю это не правильно.

Решение у меня вот такое:

```
    $dateToday = date(mktime());
    $dateOverdue = $dateToday - 24; // Вычитаем 24 часа так, как это уже просроченное время регистрации!

    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `activation`=0 AND `user_reg_date` < ???";

    $query1 = mysqli_query($query);

    # здесь вытаскиваем всех пользователей у кого статус 0 в массив
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
    do{
       # Проверяем истекла ли регистрация пользователя
       # Если истекла, то удаляем из базы данных
    }while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1));
```

помогите разобраться с датами в каком нужно формате их в базу вводить при регистрации и в каком  формате их сравинивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записывайте в базу временную метку в формате unixtime, тип переменной int
Unixtime это количество секунд прошедших с 1 января 1970.

Получите временную метку с помощью функции time()- (возвращает время на данный момент в формате unixtime) и отнимайте от нее количество секунд в сутках тоесть 86400.

$dateToday = time();
    $dateOverdue = $dateToday - 24*60*60; // Вычитаем 24 часа так, как это уже просроченное время регистрации!

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `activation`=0 AND `user_reg_date` < $dateOverdue  ";
```

Чтобы  с unixtime перевести в нормальный формат времени существует функция [date()](http://www.php.su/date)

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо!

Answer (score 1):

> Я так понимаю это не правильно.

Ну, в первую очередь, сама по себе конструкция `date(mktime())` скорее просто не имеет смысла. Вместо неё можно написать только `mktime()` без потери функциональности. Но в базу писать это значение не нужно.

> в каком нужно формате их в базу вводить при регистрации

дата должна храниться в поле типа `date`. И вставляться либо с помощью функции SQL `CURDATE()`, либо значения, передаваемого из РНР функцией `date("Y-m-d")`.

> и в каком формате их сравнивать

сравнивать в том же формате, в котором храним. Если у тебя в РНР уже посчитана дата, меньше которой записи должны быть удалены, то просто подставляешь ее в запрос, в том же формате.

```
WHERE user_reg_date < ?
```

А можно посчитать и средствами mysql, в которой просто [миллион функций для работы с датой и временем](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). В данном случае нам подойдет что-то вроде

```
WHERE user_reg_date < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL ? DAY)
```

в этом случае ты передаешь в запрос только количество дней.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в таблице поле `user_reg_date` сделать типом `timestamp` а в запросе писать сразу:

```
SELECT 'id' FROM `users` WHERE `activation`=0 AND `user_reg_date` < NOW();
```

Информация по указанию времени [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). Если использовать `time()` в php, то её стоит преобразовать используя SQL: `FROM_UNIXTIME()`